# Dealing with maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

can someone explain the mistake i'm doing in the second function. the first one working fine but the second one changing data from the original map (_filtersWithValueÏ)

```
void searchInFilter(String MainKey, String searchKey) {
final data = _filtersWithValue[MainKey]!.where((element) {
  return element.keys.first.toLowerCase().contains(searchKey.toLowerCase());
}).toList();
log(data.length.toString());
_searchFiltersWithValue = _searchFiltersWithValue.map((key, value) {
  if (key == MainKey) {
    return MapEntry(key, data);
  }
  return MapEntry(key, value);
});

notifyListeners();
```

}

```
 void searchInFilter(String MainKey, String searchKey) {
final data = _filtersWithValue[MainKey]!.where((element) {
  return element.keys.first.toLowerCase().contains(searchKey.toLowerCase());
}).toList();
log(data.length.toString());
 _searchFiltersWithValue[MainKey] = data;

notifyListeners();
```

}

Comment: What is it that your're trying to achieve?

Comment: i have a Map<String<List<Map<string,bool>>>> and i want to search in the list